# Should you 'defer/async' your script tags containing jQuery, underscore and the like?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I ran the Google Pagespeed Insights on my page and was advised to

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Among several scripts included on my page, the tool singled out libraries like jQuery, underscore and some others.

Now, I know that adding the keyword `defer` or `async` to my script tags would cause the files to be downloaded in parallel while the page processing continues.

I read this article for a deeper understanding:
https://www.sitepoint.com/non-blocking-async-defer/

I'm given to understand that as long as we're sure that the script being deferred doesn't contain stuff like `document.write()` (which could modify the page itself), it's okay to use `defer`/`async`. I checked in the jquery source code and there indeed is no occurrence of `document.write`.

However, I'm concerned that the other scripts that depend on jquery or other libraries to be there might be affected if these files are deferred.

Hence, my questions:

- Is it a good idea to defer/async my library files to improve performance
- If yes, which I should I prefer? Defer or async?
- If I do this, will I need to make any changes in my other scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: `defer` preserve the loading order so if jquery's script tag is before your other script's tag, there should be no problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks @n00dl3

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a good idea to defer/async my library files to improve performance

Yes, when done correctly.

> If yes, which I should I prefer? Defer or async?

That is entirely dependant on what the script does, what access to the DOM it requires, and what other script dependencies it has.

> If I do this, will I need to make any changes in my other scripts?

Possibly, again it depends on the above caveats.

With that said, I personally find that async/defer can cause more problems than it really solves.

Using a good bundling/minification system to join and compress all your JS files is a much quicker, easier and, generally speaking, more effective solution.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please elaborate on this part:
"what the script does, what access to the DOM it requires, and what other script dependencies it has". I just want to know when is it safe.